# Scientific number formatting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    fld AS val, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(fld, 'E2')) AS _2decimal, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(fld, 'E3')) AS _3decimal
```

Result:

| val | _2decimal | _3decimal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0000007018 | 7.02E-006 | 7.018E-006 |

The `FORMAT` function does the job fine with SQL Server (as of 2012).

I'm looking for the functions doing the same job but with older versions of SQL Server.

Thank you

Comment: `convert(varchar(20), cast(fld as float), 1)` The cast to float is obviously unnecessary if you've already got a float column.

Comment: @shawnt00

The result of your query give me:
`7.0180000e-006`

What I need for result is:
`7.02E-006`

Comment: There's a reason `FORMAT` was added; your only choices for formatting floating-point before that are the aforementioned `CONVERT` with a flag and `STR`, which is even worse. Doubtlessly you can cobble something together with `LOG`, conversions to `DECIMAL` and some tricky calculations, or else some equally tricky string manipulation, but equally doubtlessly you should push very hard for this formatting to be done at the client side, and not within SQL Server. Given that all versions prior to SQL Server 2012 are well out of even extended support, that doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: Speaking of `CONVERT`, in your original code there is 1) no reason to `CONVERT` to a string since `FORMAT` already produces one and 2) no excuse for using `VARCHAR` without a length, that's a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Formatting is a front end problem... so shouldn't typically be solved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
select f, p, f_fmt
from (values (0.0000007018e, 2), (0.0000007018, 3)) as t(f, p)
cross apply (select
    case when sign(f) = -1 then 1 else 0 end,
    p + 2 + case when sign(f) = -1 then 1 else 0 end
) as val0(f_isneg, f_len) cross apply (select
    round(cast(
        left(convert(varchar(24), f, 2), f_len + 1)
        as decimal(18, 16)), p)
) as val1(f_rnd) cross apply (select
        convert(varchar(24),
            case when abs(f_rnd) = 10
                then power(10e, ceiling(log(abs(f)) / log(10))) else f end, 2)
) as val2(f_convert) cross apply (select
    replace(stuff(
        f_convert, 1, 17 + f_isneg,
        left(
            cast(round(cast(
                left(f_convert, f_len + 1)
                as decimal(18, 16)), p) as varchar(24)),
            f_len)), '.', replicate('.', sign(p)))            
) as val3(f_fmt)
```

This is all easily inlined if necessary with `cross apply`.

The assumptions are that `convert(varchar, float, 2)` returns a value with exactly 15 decimal places (which is documented as "always 16" counting the lead digit.) Since it's scientific notation there will be a leading digit and decimal place which is where the `+2` comes into play. If the value is negative then the string is one character longer.

The trickiest part is all the rounding behavior. Negative signs throw a small curveball as well. Fourteen places is the maximum because of the rounding portion. If you need 15 places then just grab the original output of `convert(varchar, f, 2)` instead.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b39ae98e8b301d475941bddec7eaea42

Comment: Note that there is actually a syntax for floating-point constants, so the `CAST` from a decimal isn't strictly necessary (even ignoring the fact that it would be implicitly converted anyway): `0.000000170186e` (or `0.000000170186e0`, in full) is a `FLOAT` literal. Not a hugely useful thing to have, but still.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That was just a remnant of my initial comment much earlier and testing it out.

Comment: Worth noting is that while it's enough to meet the OP's requirements, this errors out when `@places` goes over 6, which is less than `FLOAT` supports. You can stretch it some more by using `CONVERT(..., 2)` and increasing the length of the character and decimal types.

Comment: @mlu Make sure you get the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Using `LEFT` & `RIGHT` & `ROUND` it can generate that format without `FORMAT`.

> ```
> SELECT fld
> , CONCAT(ROUND(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(FLOAT,fld),1),9),2), UPPER(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(FLOAT,fld),1),5))) AS _2decimal
> , CONCAT(ROUND(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(FLOAT,fld),1),9),3), UPPER(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(FLOAT,fld),1),5))) AS _3decimal
> FROM (values
> (1.2345E-6), 
> (-1.2345E-6), 
> (0.0000007018)
> ) q(fld)
> ```

> | fld | _2decimal | _3decimal |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1.2345E-06 | 1.23E-006 | 1.234E-006 |
> | -1.2345E-06 | -1.23E-006 | -1.234E-006 |
> | 7.018E-07 | 7.02E-007 | 7.018E-007 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=feff3451d8958854df077dc9eba752d1)*

Comment: Add the output of `FORMAT(fld, 'E3')` to compare; this doesn't round correctly. (`9.9999E` is an especially insightful case.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fixed. Now with rounding and also works for the negative values.